# Pull data from a jQuery input box

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have found a lovely bit of jQuery for a pop out calender. However I want to use the date(s) the user selects in a Stored Procedure. To keep this example simple how do I pull/push this date to say label?

I have tried putting the label into the function but without joy.

The date shows in   `<input type="text" id="datepickerStart" />`

but not...

```
 <asp:Label ID="lbltest" runat="server" type="text" />
```

---

```
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
      $(function () {
          $("#datepickerStart").datepicker({
              showOn: "button",
              buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
              buttonImageOnly: true

          });
          $("#datepickerEnd").datepicker({
              showOn: "button",
              buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
              buttonImageOnly: true

          });
      });




  </script>
```

Comment: What version of asp is your project? An asp label just creates a span in html, do you just want the innerHtml of the span to contain the text from your datepicker?

Comment: You'll need the `ClientID` of the label - the `ID` is server-side only, not client-side.  Show us the rendered HTML.

Comment: asp.net 4, the issue I have is how do I get the value that appears in the <input .... > as I want to use this elsewhere. I can store the value in the label or if there is a better way let me know. I have not used jquery (bar the usual fading banners) but this looked like the right road to go down for this.

Comment: If you just want to access the data in the code behind, you should be able to do that anyway. You can add `runat="server` to any html tag and read the value in the code behind. If it is not an existing tag, you can declare it an an `HtmlGenericControl`. Also, if you are using asp 4, you can add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to keep the id the same between client and server.

Comment: Any chance you can make that as a nice example - I jumped from VB6 so somewhat of a learning curve at times! (like now!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method I used to use was to declare the ID name as a variable in JavaScript, for example:

```
<script>
      var lbltest = '<%= lbltest.ClientId %>';
      function setLabel (yourDate)
      {
          $("#" + lbltest).text(yourDate);
      }

      $(function () {
          $("#datepickerStart").datepicker({
              showOn: "button",
              buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
              buttonImageOnly: true,
              onSelect: setLabel

          });
          $("#datepickerEnd").datepicker({
              showOn: "button",
              buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
              buttonImageOnly: true,
              onSelect: setLabel    
          });
      });

</script>
```

I have presumed you are using the Datepicker Widget from jQueryUI

As you can see, the "onSelect" property defines which function should be called when the user selects a date.

That then triggers the update of the label.

Comment: Thanks - I assume I need to change "yourDate" to something else?

Comment: Hi @indofraiser, yes "yourDate" should be whatever variable returned from your jquery plugin

Comment: So I tried putting datepickerStart in there and it says it is undefined. I put 
    $("#" + lbltest).text(datepickerStart); within the </script> is that the right place?

Comment: Hi @indofraiser, I've updated the example which, hopefully, should work for you